# How to handle DBNull Value

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, dbnull

```
dataGrid.DataSource = customDS.customDT.AsEnumerable()  
                      .GroupBy(r => r.Field("someID"))                  
                      .Select(g => {                      
                          CustomDS.customRow row = customDS.customDT.NewcustomRow();                      
                          row["someID"] = g.Key;                      
                          row["Tradingdate"] = g.First().Tradingdate;                      
                          row["MemberNo"] = ((object)g.First().MemberNo == DBNull.Value) ? "a" : "b";                      
                          row["Amt"] = (decimal?)g.Sum(r => r.Field("Amt"));                      
                          return row;                  
                       }).CopyToDataTable();
```

I have the above code which throwing exception because `MemberNo` is `DBNull` in `customDT`. In the above case I don't understand as already applying checking explicitly by converting to object and compare against DBNull, and hardcode to string `a` or `b`

Comment: What is wrong with g.First().MemberNo == null?

Comment: What exception you get exactly?

Comment: Are you sure that `g.First()` has property `MemberNo `. If `customDT` is of type `DataTable` then `g .First()` should be `DataRow`

Comment: can you try out my answer , that will work i think

Comment: `g.First().Field<string>("MemberNo") == null ? "a" : "b"`.  DataRow `.Field<string>(columnName)` will return `null` if field contains `DbNull`

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle DBNull value Like this:

```
row["CancelledDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : 
                          Convert.ToDateTime(row["CancelledDate"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created generic method to get value and handle `DBNull` scenario

```
 public static T GetColumnValue<T>(string columnName, DataRow dr)
 {
    Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

    //dr.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName)
    //this line can be removed if you are sure you are going to get columns 
    //it all depends on requirement and preference
    return dr.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName) && dr[columnName] != DBNull.Value
                ? (T) Convert.ChangeType(dr[columnName] , typeParameterType)
                : default(T);
 }
```

you just try like this

```
 row["MemberNo"] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetColumnValue("MemberNo", g.First())) 
                                                               ? "a" : "b";
```

Comment: this already exists: `DataRow.Field<DateTime?>("columnName");` ;)

Comment: @Fabio - not getting you ?

Comment: if columnName not exists in the table, I prefer to throw exception, then hide it behind default value.

Comment: @Fabio - that is based on requirement , in my code i have sp which if pass getall=1 it returns all columns from table and if pass getall=0 then it not returns some of columns , and i have code common for getting data so i needed it , if there no need that OP remove that part, there no big deal in that

Comment: `g.First().Field<DateTime?>("MemberNo")` will return nullable `DateTime` with value or without if field contain `DbNull.Value`

Comment: @Fabio - dont see anything reagrding DateTime in question, what is your point can you please explain

Comment: `DateTime` was just for example. In OP case it would be `string`. Where `g.First().Field<string>("MemberNo")` will return `null` if field contain `DbNull`. No need for manual converting

Comment: @Fabio - again it all your preference , it you like that way then you go ahead it with , but in my code I dont want to write code again and again for checking null stuff, I want it to write once only and reutilize it every where , as I am dealing with table having 100 fields

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that MemberNo can be null.
Then you cannot use result of First(), without null check.
Instead, use `g.FirstOrDefault()`.

```
var m = g.FirstOrDefault();
row["MemberNo"] = m != null ? "a" : "b";
```

Comment: it group by clause , and first should be there ...otherwise there will be no group

Comment: another point is its group by on datarow, that means return value of First() going to be datarow

Answer (score 0):

```
row["MemberNo"] = g.First().IsMemberNoNull() ? "a" : "b";
```

Apparently there is a `IscolumnnameNull()` method can be invoked to handle `DBNull` value?